# Why Marker object is not getting passed.? Why Marker not getting Cleared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a page on which I have four maps. And Every time I drag a element(vehicle Number) from table on to a map. The map shows its  location.

Here is my ASP code

```
        <input type="hidden" id="hf_div1" class="hf" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hf_div2" class="hf" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hf_div3" class="hf" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hf_div4" class="hf" />
        <%--  <div class="divDateTime">
        </div>--%>
        <asp:Panel ID="divContainer" runat="server" CssClass="containerPanel">
            <div class="innerDivClass ui-state-highlight" id="div1">

            </div>
            <div class="innerDivClass ui-state-highlight" id="div2">

            </div>
            <div class="innerDivClass ui-state-highlight" id="div3">

            </div>
            <div class="innerDivClass ui-state-highlight" id="div4">

            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Here is My jQuery

```
var arrayOfMapobjects = [];
var map1 = null;
var map2 = null;
var map3 = null;
var map4 = null;
var mrkr_div1;
var mrkr_div2;
var mrkr_div3;
var mrkr_div4;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdVehicleList span').draggable({ helper: 'clone' });

    $('.innerDivClass').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var IDtoBeFound = 'hf_' + $(this).attr('id');
            //alert(IDtoBeFound);
            //alert(ui.draggable.attr('title'));
            var deviceID = ui.draggable.attr('title');
            //alert(deviceID);
            //alert('#' + IDtoBeFound);

            $('#' + IDtoBeFound).val(deviceID);

        }
    });
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div1'), mapOptions);
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div2'), mapOptions);
    map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div3'), mapOptions);
    map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div4'), mapOptions);
    mrkr_div1 = new google.maps.Marker();
    mrkr_div2 = new google.maps.Marker();
    mrkr_div3 = new google.maps.Marker();
    mrkr_div4 = new google.maps.Marker();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.innerDivClass').each(function() {
            var account = $('#ctl00_sessionValue').val();
            console.log(account);
            var deviceID = $('#hf_' + $(this).attr('id')).val();
            //            alert('device ID is' + deviceID);
            //            console.log(deviceID);
            var mapObject = null;
            var markerobject = null;
            var divID = null;


            // I am assigning the values here, here is the actual problem... Please see the code below and tell me the problem :(



            if (deviceID != null && deviceID.trim() != '') {
                if ($(this).attr('id').match("1$")) {
                    mapObject = map1;
                    markerobject = mrkr_div1;
                }
                else if ($(this).attr('id').match("2$")) {
                    // alert('2');
                    mapObject = map2;
                    markerobject = mrkr_div2;
                }
                else if ($(this).attr('id').match("3$")) {
                    //alert('3');
                    mapObject = map3;
                    markerobject = mrkr_div3;
                }
                if ($(this).attr('id').match("4$")) {
                    // alert('4');
                    mapObject = map4;
                    markerobject = mrkr_div4;
                }


                getData(account, deviceID, mapObject, markerobject);
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
});

function getData(accountID, deviceID, mapObject, markerObject) {

    //    var account = $('#ctl00_sessionValue').val();
    //    var deviceID=$(
    //    var device=$(
    var dataToBePassed = { accountID: accountID, deviceID: deviceID };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MultiVehicleTracking.aspx/getLastDpOFDevice",   // call pageMethod on js_Dashboard.aspx
        data: JSON.stringify(dataToBePassed), // to convert in JSON format
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // type to be processed is JSON
        success: function(msg) {
            drawMap(JSON.parse(msg.d), mapObject, markerObject); // push the data in to array for further use and process the same
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log('Error: ' + status);  // display the erro messsage if request failed
        }
    });

}
function drawMap(jsonData, mapObj, markerObject) {
    if (markerObject != null) {
        markerObject.setMap(null);
        markerObject = null;
    }
    else {
        alert('marker is null');
    }
    var lat = jsonData[0].latitude;
    var lng = jsonData[0].longitude;
    alert(jsonData[0].imagePath);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(jsonData[0].imagePath,
                                                     null,
                                                     null,
                                                      new google.maps.Point(5, 17), //(15,27),
                                                     new google.maps.Size(30, 30));
    markerObject = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: image,
        title: jsonData[0].address
    });

    markerObject.setMap(mapObj);
    mapObj.panTo(myLatLng);
    mapObj.setZoom(14);
}
```

In the above code, I am passing the map and marker objects to the function depending upon the ID of the div,.
The map opject is behaving fine but the marker object is not getting passed into the function. When I am trying to do markerObject.setmap(null); is it not working. Similarly markerObject=null is also not working. What Am it doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
....match("1$"))
```

match should have a regular expression, you have a string

```
.match(/1$/))
```

and you are missing the else on the last if in that group.

Comment: Fixed the changes you told and still not working..  Please Help.. :(

Comment: Did you add console lines to make sure that the object is being set correctly?

Comment: Yes.. After Every Iteration i've logged the JSON.stringify(markerObject) and got this in my console {"gm_accessors_":{"clickable":null,"visible":null},"clickable":true,"gm_bindings_":{"clickable":{},"visible":{}},"visible":true}